# Debugging spring dependency in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I'm creating a module for a Spring application. The way it works is that the main application includes modules and when it runs it picks up on its Spring annotations. So it ends up being two different projects on two different windows in IntelliJ.

So to run my module, I have to `mvn install` it in the local repository and then it run the application which includes it in the `<dependencies>`.

I have both projects open in IntelliJ. I set a breakpoint in the module, run the main application, and call the endpoint defined in the module. It doesn't stop, which I expected. Is there a way to do something equivalent to debug my module? I need the outside application because of the database and configurations, so I can't run the module directly.

Comment: You'll need to to open up the dependency as a library from within IntelliJ (or, perhaps more directly, just open them both in the same project). This is entirely normal; use Find Anything to open up your class. This may be a learning experience in why to enable the `maven-source-plugin`. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose there are 2 modules A and B where B module is added as dependency in module A. If you want to debug the code flow from A to B, instead of putting breakpoint in B project (imported in IntelliJ) you have to put breakpoint in module A only.

[image: You can find dependency in External Libraries]

You must be aware of package of the class in module B, so you can navigate to that class from external libraries and put breakpoint on required method of class in module B.

Open the depedency class of project B inside A and attach the breakpoints.

Run application A with debug mode on, your depedency in B project will get hit eventually.

Comment: How do I find module B inside module A? As I said, module A doesn't directly call module B - I just included it as a dependency inside the pom.xml and it works by itself. Module B has the Spring annotations for the endpoints so it just works.